# Auto Login Client with Basic Auth to other website using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, authentication, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have one website lets call it AutoLoginSite (http://mainsite.dev)
and the other website which need Basic Authentication to surfing other page lets call it MainSite (**I can't touch it**)

So when user open url from AutoLoginSite, it will redirect to MainSite with authenticated status.

So what I try is, I create autologin controller in AutoLoginSite app using Spring Boot, here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public void login(HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
    String loginUri = "http://mainsite.dev/authenticate";
    String redirectUri = "http://mainsite.dev/my-account/cards";
    String username = "customer";
    String password = "c123";

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes());

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(loginUri);
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("Status : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    servletResponse.setHeader("Location", redirectUri);
    servletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

I know I'm doing it wrong because the authenticated user is the AutoLoginSite server not the AutoLoginSite client.
How can I auto login the client to other website so they can access all MainSite secured page?

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase, You should implement OAuth 2.0. With this your **AutoLoginSite** will serve as a Authentication Server for your Resource Server **MainSite**. 
First User will have to login to your Authentication server,On the successful authentication your AutoLoginSite will issue the authorization Code Which then can be used to authorize user on your resource server.
OAuth 2 provides several “grant types” for different use cases.You need to identify your requirement and use accordingly.

Visit this article can help you to have more information on the subject. 
https://medium.com/@akourtim.ahmed/oauth-2-centralized-authorization-with-spring-boot-2-0-2-and-spring-security-5-and-jdbc-token-store-8dbc063bd5d4

Spring OAuth 2.0: 
https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html